# Reporting Template is missing in Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: c#, templates, reporting, visual-studio-2015, missing-template

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

Now I am trying to create new report(.rdlc) from Add New Item Dialog

But I am not able to View Reporting Template option in my Add New Item Wizard, Below is the image of my Issue: 
[image]

Can anyone please help me how to add Reporting Template in Add New Item Wizard

Thanks in Advance

Mr. GO

Comment: same here, no crystal reports template in VS 2015 :(

Comment: Anybody has the same issue with VS 2019 CE? I have tried all advices pointed here (repair installation, update vsix RDLC report designer ) and have no luck. Please, I need another advice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Got to Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features.

Select you Visual Studio Version, right click and 'Change'.

The Visual Studio Setup splashscreen should appear, Click on Modify at
the bottom left, and then under 'Windows and Web Development' select 
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools. The Reporting option should then appear in 
your installed updates.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue with visual studio community 2017 even after installing "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools".

You need to install the report designer from Microsoft. Once you do that, the report and report wizard will then appear in your installed tools under the programming language of your choice.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2017 install "Data storage and processing".

And then install Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services tools, also known as "SSDT for VS 2017 (standalone installer)"

[Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.2)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2038031)

Here is the full info from Microsoft.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer)

Answer (score 1):

Even if "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools" is being installed, be noticed that in form "Add new Item", instead of look for "Reporting" item , Click on "Visual C# Items" and in second column go down and select "Report" or "Report wizard".

I don't Know why this movement is not noticed any where. I was looking for "Reporting" title all a day!

Answer (score 0):

In the extension and updates windows, Download and install Microsoft SQL Server Update for database tooling, that will add the reporting servers template even to the release version of Visual Studio 2015 up to enterprise.