# Crystal reports for Visual studio 2015 community: 'New item' report template missing

Tags: templates, crystal-reports

As the title says, i cannot see the Crystal report template
[image]

The winforms toolbox item **does** appear.

Here is everything i have done:

1. Installed the click once "Homesite" 64 bit option from this page: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
2. Uninstalled VS2015 with manual steps to remove regedit entries and some other folders
3. Reinstalled latest VS2015
4. Enabled .Net 3.5 in "Turn windows features on and off"
5. Followed both answers on this similar question: [Reporting Template is missing in Visual Studio 2015 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137453/reporting-template-is-missing-in-visual-studio-2015-preview)
6. Enabled .Net 4.6 framework
7. Attempted the solution on the last comment on this page:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/615e462d-58ba-4572-8a31-0ec92debde0f/no-crystal-report-item-in-new-item?forum=vscrystalreports
   However, there were no CyrstalReports.Zip files from step one.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was in using the clickonce file. This is an MSI file and as noted on the site, you need to use the .exeon the left column.